# How do I check if accessibility permission has been turned on after I go back to my app screen

Tags: java, android

How do I check if accessibility permission has been turned on after I go back to my app screen.

**that's the part that makes him ask for permission.**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onResume()`, you can use this for checking:

```
    public static boolean isAccessibilityEnabled(Context context, Class<?> accessibilityService) {
        ComponentName expectedComponentName = new ComponentName(context, accessibilityService);
        String enabledServicesSetting = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "enabled_accessibility_services");
        if (enabledServicesSetting == null) {
            return false;
        }
        TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter colonSplitter = new TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter(':');
        colonSplitter.setString(enabledServicesSetting);
        while (colonSplitter.hasNext()) {
            ComponentName enabledService = ComponentName.unflattenFromString(colonSplitter.next());
            if (enabledService != null && enabledService.equals(expectedComponentName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```